# model inheriting doesn't work out well

Tags: python, django, json, model

I want 2 models to work as following:
A Content class that inherits from Link class.
Sounds simple.
here's my models (relevant part) :

```
class Link(models.Model):
     name               = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     slug               = models.SlugField(unique = True)
     level              = models.IntegerField(default='1')
     vectorImage        = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
     parent             = models.TextField(default='index')
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class Content(Link):
     context            = models.TextField()
```

The problem is that when I create a new Content, it creates a link separately and a content separately.
So if I transfer it with JSON:

Links.objects.all... and Content.objects.all, after creating 1 Content :

```
 [{
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "grid.link",
        "fields": {
            "vectorImage": "",
            "level": 1,
            "name": "logo",
            "parent": "index",
            "slug": "logo"
        }
    }
],
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "grid.contexthtml",
        "fields": {
            "context": "html codez"
        }
    }
]
```

That's not what I want. I want it to send the full Content ( like above, but with combine fields).
How do I fix this?
 I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).  Does this work for you?

```
class BaseLink(models.Model):
     name               = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     slug               = models.SlugField(unique = True)
     level              = models.IntegerField(default='1')
     vectorImage        = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
     parent             = models.TextField(default='index')

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

     class Meta:
         abstract = True

class Link(BaseLink):
    pass


class Content(BaseLink):
     context            = models.TextField()
```

Comment: I thought about that,  but I thought it was dumb to make the 2 Links classes. strange. I guess that will work. I will check.

Comment: It does feel strange, but that's what it's for.